# TextField keyboardType text

Tags: ios, flutter, keyboard, textfield

I'm unable to find a way to solve this problem in Flutter. Black strip is being added When I type more than one character in TextField for iOS and for android its working fine. Attached image for more clarity about the question and added code snippet below.

```
          TextField(
                    autofocus: true,
                    textInputAction: TextInputAction.search,
                    focusNode: _focus,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                      focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
                      contentPadding:
                      EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 15.0, 0.0, 15.0),
                      hintText: "Type to search products",
                    ),
                    onSubmitted: (value) {
                      searchValue = value;
                    },
                    )
```

[image]

Comment: Provide your code snippet please

Comment: Added code snippet in the question